# VirtualBox and Windows 8 - No USB connectivity?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, usb-flash-drive, windows-8-preview

I've tried using 4 different pen drives with my Windows 8 virtual machine in VirtualBox and for some reason it just won't show.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you run VirtualBox on Linux? If so, are you running the OS Edition?

Comment: Running it on Windows7!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to realize that Windows 8 is not yet released. This is the most likely cause.

However it is possible that you did not install Virtual Machine Guest Additions? That might fix it...

Comment: It is certainly installed.

Comment: Can you confirm that USB does work with other OS'es (other than Windows 8)? If not, it may be that your configuration is wrong somehow - perhaps you did not install the USB driver properly on the original installation of VirtualBox.